# how to insert data from one function into multiple widgets in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyserial

I have a device connected with my interface and want to insert the data into `QlineEdit` widgets

This function `def getdevice_data(self):` receaves the data from the device and returns it as string

with `self.get_output__button.clicked.connect(self.getdevice_data)` I "start" the function

and with `self.custom_attribute.connect(self.device_input1.setText)` I send the output to the `QLineEdit` widget

How can I keep the function running and  insert the new data from the function into empty line edit widgets, without adding multiple buttons to start the function again and again ?

full code

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg

import serial
import time


class CustmClass(qtw.QWidget):
    '''
    description einfügen
    '''

    # Attribut Signal
    custom_attribute = qtc.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # your code will go here


        # Interface
        self.resize(300, 210)
        # button
        self.get_output__button = qtw.QPushButton("start function ?")
        # lineEdit
        self.device_input1 = qtw.QLineEdit()
        self.device_input2 = qtw.QLineEdit()
        # Layout
        vboxlaout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        vboxlaout.addWidget(self.get_output__button)
        vboxlaout.addWidget(self.device_input1)
        vboxlaout.addWidget(self.device_input2)

        self.setLayout(vboxlaout)


        self.show()

        # Funktionalität

        self.get_output__button.clicked.connect(self.getdevice_data)

        self.custom_attribute.connect(self.device_input1.setText)
        # self.custom_attribute.connect(self.device_input2.setText)

    def getdevice_data(self):
        try:
            # Serial() opens a serial port
            my_serial = serial.Serial(port='COM6', baudrate=2400, bytesize=7,
                                      parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, timeout=None, stopbits=1)

            if my_serial.is_open:  
                print("port open")
                # log einfügen
                while my_serial.is_open:  

                    data = my_serial.read()  # wait forever till data arives
                    time.sleep(1)  # delay 

                    data_left = my_serial.inWaiting()  
                    data += my_serial.read(data_left)  

                    data = data.decode("utf-8", "strict")

                    if type(data) == str:
                        print(data)
                        return self.custom_attribute.emit(data)
            else:
                print("zu")

        except serial.serialutil.SerialException:
            print("not open")
            # logger hinzufügen


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = CustmClass()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason for those `time.sleep` or are they there to emulate the wait?

Comment: `time.sleep` is to make sure to get all the data from the device

Comment: @HoboCoder Explain better what you mean, your question is confusing.

Comment: @eyllanesc hope the edit make it less confusing

Comment: @HoboCoder Okay, I understand you better. I still have the following doubts: 1) If you remove the time.sleep() your code still works? 2) How many QLineEdits do you have to add the text? Are they only 2 QLineEdits? Assume that the information was emitted twice, so 2 QLineEdits have already been filled, in a next emit to which QLineEdit should that text be placed?

Comment: @eyllanesc  without time sleep the code did not work. //to clarify : I have a device wich when I push a button on the device I trasnmit the data to the function. with this code so far I can not continuously receave new data.and add it to new line edit/ What I want is to keep the function running and add each new output to a empty line edit so far I can only add one single output to multiple line eddit widgets

Comment: @HoboCoder Mmm, I don't understand your answer. Be more detailed and answer my questions clearly. The answer to the first question and I understand it but not to the second question: Assuming that text has been placed in both QLineEdit If new text comes, should the text be placed in the first QLineEdit, or in the second QLineEdit or should a new one be created? new QLineEdit? please use `@username`

Comment: @eyllanesc my function waits for incoming data and returns it as a string I. I want add sequentially each empty line edit with the data/ if lineedit1 is full insert it to lineedit2 and so on

Comment: @HoboCoder And if lineedit2 is full where the new text should be inserted?

Comment: @eyllanesc if all lineedits receaved an input the insert of new data should stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not execute time-consuming or time-consuming loops in the main thread since they block the event loop. What you must do is execute it on a secondary thread and send the information through signals. To obtain the data sequentially you can create an iterator and access each element through the next() function

```py
import sys
import threading
import time

import serial

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg


class SerialWorker(qtw.QObject):
    dataChanged = qtw.pyqtSignal(str)

    def start(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self._execute, daemon=True).start()

    def _execute(self):
        try:
            my_serial = serial.Serial(
                port="COM6",
                baudrate=2400,
                bytesize=7,
                parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                timeout=None,
                stopbits=1,
            )
            while my_serial.is_open:
                data = my_serial.read()  # wait forever till data arives
                time.sleep(1)  # delay
                data_left = my_serial.inWaiting()
                data += my_serial.read(data_left)
                data = data.decode("utf-8", "strict")
                print(data)
                self.dataChanged.emit(data)
        except serial.serialutil.SerialException:
            print("not open")


class Widget(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300, 210)
        self.get_output__button = qtw.QPushButton("start function ?")
        self.device_input1 = qtw.QLineEdit()
        self.device_input2 = qtw.QLineEdit()
        # Layout
        vboxlaout = qtw.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vboxlaout.addWidget(self.get_output__button)
        vboxlaout.addWidget(self.device_input1)
        vboxlaout.addWidget(self.device_input2)

        self.serial_worker = SerialWorker()

        self.device_iterator = iter([self.device_input1, self.device_input2])

        self.get_output__button.clicked.connect(self.serial_worker.start)
        self.serial_worker.dataChanged.connect(self.on_data_changed)

    @qtw.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_data_changed(self, data):
        try:
            device = next(self.device_iterator)
            device.setText(data)
        except StopIteration:
            pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = CustmClass()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thank you very much @eyllanesc ! , tried to avoid threading so far I guess I need to dive into it know